yolov5 trained my data set on my laptop how I send it to my Raspberry Pi
I got yolov5 and trained my data set on my laptop now I want to send it to my Raspberry Pi 4b module for work. how I do it
direct copy to raspberry pi but not working
(myenv) h@raspberrypi:~/project/yolov5 $ python3 detect.py --weights /home/hasha/project/yolov5/runs/train/crosswalk_detection/weights/crosswalk_detection_best.pt --source /home/hasha/project/1.jpg
detect: weights=['/home/hasha/project/yolov5/runs/train/crosswalk_detection/weights/crosswalk_detection_best.pt'], source=/home/hasha/project/1.jpg, data=data/coco128.yaml, imgsz=[640, 640], conf_thres=0.25, iou_thres=0.45, max_det=1000, device=, view_img=False, save_txt=False, save_csv=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, nosave=False, classes=None, agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, visualize=False, update=False, project=runs/detect, name=exp, exist_ok=False, line_thickness=3, hide_labels=False, hide_conf=False, half=False, dnn=False, vid_stride=1
YOLOv5  v7.0-335-g40f490d9 Python-3.11.2 torch-2.3.1 CPU

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hasha/project/yolov5/detect.py", line 313, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "/home/hasha/project/yolov5/detect.py", line 308, in main
    run(**vars(opt))
  File "/home/hasha/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hasha/project/yolov5/detect.py", line 116, in run
    model = DetectMultiBackend(weights, device=device, dnn=dnn, data=data, fp16=half)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hasha/project/yolov5/models/common.py", line 467, in __init__
    model = attempt_load(weights if isinstance(weights, list) else w, device=device, inplace=True, fuse=fuse)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hasha/project/yolov5/models/experimental.py", line 98, in attempt_load
    ckpt = torch.load(attempt_download(w), map_location="cpu")  # load
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hasha/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1025, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hasha/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1446, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/pathlib.py", line 874, in __new__
    raise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"
NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system
(myenv) h@raspberrypi:~/project/yolov5 $ 

